# USB to SPI line level converter

Tags: usb, spi

I have a quite powerful DSO, MSO2024 from Tektronix with SPI interpreter on board. 
Any idea to convert USB line levels to SPI so I can watch them with this scope?

Answer (score 4):

USB lines are differential data lines, and use a different type of encoding than SPI. There is no practical way of converting them.

Comment: Also no point I'd have thought, the scope is more than capable of watching USB signals without conversion.

Comment: @JohnU they did say SPI interpreter. As in decodes and displays the spi messages, not just the raw signal. You could view the raw usb signal, but unless you understand the differential pairs, and the encoding, it won't make sense.

Comment: Missed that, the term "watch" misled me... but as you rightly point out, SPI is a different protocol altogether, and decoding USB is not a simple task - there is a good looking USB protocol analyser for the very useful DSO Quad here: http://essentialscrap.com/dsoquad/index.html